# Python | ctypes structure return pointer

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm hoping for some help with ctypes structures and pointers.

Here is my C code signatures

```
typedef struct ApiReturn
{
   int error;
   char* errorMessage;
} ApiReturn;

// if this call fails, we'll declare instantiate the errorMessage pointer and
// set the appropriate value for error.
ApiReturn DoSomething();

// this frees the memory in clear.
void Api_Clear(char* clear);
```

And here's the ctypes code:

```
class ApiReturn(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('error', c_int),
                ('errorMessage', c_char_p)]

def check_api_return(api_return):
    # 0 means api call succeeded.
    if api_return.error != 0:
        get_global_lib().Api_Clear(api_return.errorMessage)
        raise Exception('API call failed with' + api_return.errorMessage)

do_something = get_global_lib().DoSomething
do_something.restype = ApiReturn
```

This python code is wrong because api_return.errorMessage has instantiated a new python string, but I'm having trouble accessing the pointer errorMessage directly through the *field* member.

The rest of the library is working as expected. I'd appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question after spending more time researching it. It turns out I needed to define the python structure differently in order to access the pointer.

```
class ApiReturn(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('error', c_int),
                ('errorMessage', POINTER(c_char))]

cp = pointer(api_return).contents.errorMessage
error_msg = cast(cp, c_char_p).value
get_global_lib().Api_Clear(cp)
```

Comment: See also [ctypes.create_string_buffer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer) and [byref()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.byref)